# How do I mask/hide an IP address (string) using PHP and Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I would like to hide the last two sections from an IP address using regular expression the problem is that the asterix (`*`) must match the length of those sections.

Eg: `10.101.12.100` should be re-formated into `10.101.**.***`

This is the code I'm working with :

```
echo preg_replace('!(\d+).(\d+).\d+.\d+!s', '${1}.${2}.***.***', "10.101.12.100");
// Return: 10.101.***.***
```

Is that possible using regex ?

**PS:** I know I could break it using `explode('.', ...)` along with `str_repeat('*', strlen(...))` but I find `preg_replace` a cleaner solution. I'm looking for a "oneliner" solution.

Comment: Only with a custom callback. And then I guess the `exlode` version is easier.... Why does it always have to be one line? You should put this in a function anyway and then you have a "oneliner".

Comment: @Felix, custom callback could be a solution. Ok it's not one liner but it's probably cleaner then a `explode` solution.

Comment: @Cybrix: in jest I will say that you must have an odd sense of "clean" :)

Comment: @Andrew, using `explode` it's atleast (when keeping readable code) a 4-5 lines of codes. when a `preg_replace` could use one line (if I find a solution...)

Comment: To be fair, anything can be done on one line if you try hard enough.  For example, you can use the explode solution as a "one liner" too:  
echo $explode('.', $IP)[0].'.'.$explode('.', $IP)[1].'.***.***';  
I know this is a little redundant because you are running explode on the same variable twice, but I just wanted to show that it doesn't **have** to be 4-5 lines.

Comment: @Infotekka I am aware of that but I appreciate oneliner that are still readable. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead (Basically, have regex disqualify the first two octets, then do a normal digit replace from thereafter.) e.g.

```
(?!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)\d
```

**[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/5i9Cl)**

Example output:

```
237.134.85.92 -> 237.134.**.**
173.14.176.182 -> 173.14.***.***
167.209.41.203 -> 167.209.**.***
137.133.204.130 -> 137.133.***.***
93.108.72.157 -> 93.108.**.***
```

Comment: Thank you. You have provided a one liner solution. `echo preg_replace('/(?!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)\d/', '*', "10.101.12.100"); // Return: 10.101.**.***`

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks, every so often I can pull one over on people. ;-) -- @Cybrix: No problem. If that didn't work, I was fully prepared for a create_function/eval solution...[not really].

Answer (score 0):

That might be a bit of an abuse of a regex. The following is probably faster, safer, and easier to understand...

1. Explode string on "."
2. Replace all chars in array index 2, 3 with "*"
3. Join with "."
4. profit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was the solutions I was using already but I was just wondering if a regex solution could have been possible.