# Show part of a IP address

Tags: php, string, ip-address

`85.124.99.2`

How can I hide the last two numbers from the IP?

and make it like:

`86.124.xxx.xxx`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224156/how-do-i-mask-hide-an-ip-address-string-using-php-and-regular-expression

Comment: @ILikeTurtles am guessing you are not actually changing the ip from 85.x.x.x to 86.x.x.x

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrote this quickly

```
$ip = "85.124.99.2";
$parts = explode('.',$ip);

$new_ip = $parts[0].'.'.$parts[1].'.xxx.xxx';
```

Warning: You should test the length of parts before accessing *$parts[n]*

Answer (score 2):

```
$ip = preg_replace('/\.\d+\.\d+$/', '.xxx.xxx', $ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consume the IP Address and only print out what you want.  Not sure other than that what you mean by "make it" other than printing on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex.

```
(?!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)\d
```

Sample

```
137.133.204.130 -> 137.133.***.***  
93.108.72.157 -> 93.108.**.***
```