# using php to mask part of an ipv4 or ipv6 address

Tags: php

I'm using the code below, but it's not displaying the prefix of the ip (example .* * * . * * * . * * * is displaying instead of 192.* * * . * * * . * * * and the same goes for IPV6.

```
$offset = 2;

if (strpos($row["log_ip"], ":") !== false) {
  $needle      = ".";
  $replacement = ".***.***.***";
}
else {
  $needle      = ":";
  $replacement = ":****:****:****:****:****:****:****";
}

$row["log_ip"] = substr_replace($row["log_ip"], $replacement, stripos($row["log_ip"],     $needle, $offset));

echo $row["log_ip"];
```

Comment: As demonstrated... where?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mask/hide an IP address (string) using PHP and Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224156/how-do-i-mask-hide-an-ip-address-string-using-php-and-regular-expression)

Comment: It's not a duplicate that only orks for ipv4

Comment: i resolved the issue thanks to lucian i'll accept the answer today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to remove the exclamation mark from your condition. It should be ==false

```
        $offset = 2;
        if (strpos($row["log_ip"], ":") == false) {
        $needle      = ".";
          $replacement = ".***.***.***";
        }
        else {
          $needle      = ":";
          $replacement = ":****:****:****:****:****:****:****";
        }

        $row["log_ip"] = substr_replace($row["log_ip"], $replacement, stripos($row["log_ip"],     $needle, $offset));

    echo $row["log_ip"];
```

Comment: i seriously cannot believe i overlooked the exclamation point ill "Accept" this soon as i can

Comment: it happens when you are too focused on figuring out something else.